# Is it possible to use a generic identifier in a SELECT query in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, function

I'm creating a function for querying a SQLite database that should be generic in the sense of reading from multiple pre-defined tables. As part of the function's paremeters, it is necessary to tel which column of the table should be read, an info that is supposed to be passed by an enumerator value. So the call would be something like this:

```
callMyFunction(enumTableA,enumColumnB);
```

Since `enumColumnB` is an enumerator value, the argument is an integer and I would like to identify the column by that integer value without having to use a switch-case for that. Something like this:

```
SELECT column(enumColumnB) from ...
```

So instead of passing the name of the column or reading all columns with `*` and then selecting the desired one when reading, it would use the number of the column as passed by the enumerator value to identify what should be read.

Is it possible to do this for SQLite? I couldn't find any tutorial mentioning such possibility, so I'm almost concluding there is no such possibility (and I'll have to pass the name of the column as argument or use a switch-case at the end), but I'ld like to be sure I don't have this option available.

Comment: There is a command to list all columns of a table. It is `PRAGMA table_info ('yourtablename')` The command works like a select statement, it lists all columns . More info [here](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has no mechanism for indirect columns.
(SQLite is designed as an embedded database, i.e., to be used together with a 'real' programming language.)

You have to replace the column name in whatever programming language you're using.